Heterogeneity and ICC when using metafor's rma.mv and robust variance estimation
I am conducting a meta-analysis of standardised mean differences with many sources of dependency (multiple outcomes measuring the same construct, multiple control groups, outcomes from dyads (e.g., separate patient-carer and husband-wife scores), and multiple timepoints (post and followups)).
I used metafor::rma.mv to construct 3-level models (random = ~1|study/effectsize) in combination with RVE (metafor::robust). I have conducted sensitivity analyses with different assumptions for the constant correlations. As expected, the pooled effect and standard error is nearly identical across rho = .5, .6, .7, .8 or .9., with the same inference of a significant effect.
However, the variance components and heterogeneity are not affected by RVE and are different for different values of the correlation. e.g, I^2 ranges from 41.24 (95% CI = [3.68, 74.16]) with 39.13 on level 3  when rho is assumed to be .5, to 52.71 [30.97, 75.86] with 11.69 on level 3 when rho is assumed to be .9., and Q is similarly affected. (this post was very helpful for me when calculating the confidence intervals by reparameterising the random part of the model: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-meta-analysis/2017-September/000195.html ). The prediction intervals also differ.
Question 1:
I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions regarding cluster-robust inferences on heterogeneity? I am conducting moderator analyses to account for heterogeneity using multimodel methods (https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:model_selection_with_glmulti_and_mumin).
However, the sensitivity analyses indicate that, although significant across analyses, I do not actually know how much true heterogeneity there is.
Question 2:
I was wondering if the ICC that can be calculated after fitting the model can be used as an indication of how "right" the initial guess of the constant correlation is?
E.g.,
rma_mv_model$sigma2[1]/ sum(rma_mv_model$sigma2) 
or the "rho" value that is produced by rma.mv when reparameterising the model as
random = ~factor(effectsize)|Study

It is not entirely clear to me what 'correlation' you are changing in your sensitivity analyses. Are you maybe using vcalc() to construct an approximate variance-covariance matrix (say V) assuming different correlations for dependent estimates and feeding this into res <- rma(yi, V, ...) followed by robust(res, cluster=Study, clubSandwich=TRUE) as described here?
In any case, RVE does not affect the variance components. It is a method for computing the standard errors of the fixed effects but has no influence on the variance components of the random effects. However, changing the assumed correlation in vcalc() will indeed affect the variance components and hence $I^2$, so I guess this is what you are doing. Note that when you have a non-diagonal V matrix, you really should use W <- solve(V) in the computation of $I^2$ (and not just W <- diag(1/dat$vi) as shown under the link you posted).
As for your second question: The ICC of the model does not really tell you anything about the appropriate value for the assumed correlation in the construction of the V matrix. However, an idea that James Pustejovsky (the author of the clubSandwich package) and I (the author of the metafor package) have discussed at some point in the past is to examine to what extent the standard errors change when using the model-based estimates and when using RVE (see here and here for two threads from the archives of the R-sig-meta-analysis mailing list where this has come up). If the standard errors do not change much (assuming that the sample size is sufficiently large such that we can assume that the 'asymptotics' underlying RVE kick in), then this might be an indication that the working model is somewhat appropriate. So, one could try to find the value of the correlation that makes the two types of standard errors as similar as possible and then use the estimated variance components from that model for assessing the amount of heterogeneity.
